# Set Div Id to the value of a hidden field?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the Id of a div from the value of a hidden field, can you do this?

Even if its from page load and behind code C#. I'm just looking for anyway.

```
<div id="'img_' + document.getElementById('mainContainer_hiddenCompanyId').value;" class="arrow" onclick="return setSelection(document.getElementById('mainContainer_hiddenCompanyId').value;)" ></div>
```

I have the value in page load already if that helps with any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your div id to something else

```
<div id="no_id_yet" class="arrow" onclick="return setSelection(document.getElementById('mainContainer_hiddenCompanyId').value;)" ></div>
```

and then in js just switch id

```
div = document.getElementById('no_id_yet');
div.id = 'img_' + document.getElementById('mainContainer_hiddenCompanyId').value;
```

Comment: Thanks, just got to get the onclick right and i'm good to go, but sure it would be something similar.